# How do I pass datetimes between a controller and a view in MVC?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2

Our model has `public DateTime date { get; set; }`.  In our view, our dates are being stored in the JSON date format.  We're then trying to save updates to the date

`var someObject = {};`
`someObject.date = JSONDate;`
`$.post("Controller/SaveAction", someObject, callback);`

and our controller has `public JsonResult SaveAction(ModelType model) { ... }` but this code breaks because it is unable to convert the JSON date to a c# DateTime object.

How can I convert the JSON date to something that the post will controller will be able to correctly read into a C# DateTime object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably using the JSON.NET library, where things like this have already been defined and (more or less) standardized.

http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, while this looks like it would solve my problem, I am unfortunately unable to add external dependencies to our project.  I was hoping more for something I could do in javascript before assigning it to someObject.date.

Comment: If you just need the part that converts to DateTime, you can probably "borrow" the code from the JSON.NET library (it's licensed under a BSD-like non-restrictive license), or write a work-alike. In particular, have a look at the `JavaScriptDateTimeConverter.cs` class.